# Cannot import external JAVA library using Jython in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jython, jgraphx

I'm new to Jython and to Eclipse. I'm trying to use the JGraphX JAVA library. I've created a new PyDev project and package. I've right-clicked on the project properties in Eclipse, selected "PyDev - PYTHONPATH" and added jgraphx.jar. In the **init**.py file, I've tried:

```
import jgraphx as jgx
from jgraphx import *
```

Neither approach works. The code is underlined as an error in Eclipse. When I run, I get "ImportError: No module named jgraphx". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,
-david

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the JGraphX library.
To import a java class

you need to use `from my.project.package import someclass`